# pgadmin4 in AUTOMATED mode

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have installed and I am using `pgadmin4` okay. I would like to now automated the process of the install on the `ubuntu 20` server.

when i ran `sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh` I need to pass it an email address and password.

I have checked the script and it looks like this is possible:

```
# Is this an automated install?
AUTOMATED=0
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    AUTOMATED=1
    echo "Running in non-interactive mode..."
fi
```

Just not sure how to use it and pass the email and user in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set these env variables prior to running the script
'PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD'
'PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL'
Look at the following file
/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/setup/user_info.py

The below code works

```
if [[ ! -d "$PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL" ]]; then 
    export PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL="${pg_admin_email}"
    export PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD="${pg_admin_pwd}"
    echo 'export PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL="${pg_admin_email}"' >> ~/.bashrc
    echo 'export PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD="${pg_admin_pwd}"' >> ~/.bashrc
fi
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
apt install -y pgadmin4
apt install -y pgadmin4-web 
sudo apt update
# silently install the below --yes indicate auto install
. /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh --yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this answer and I ended up setting the envs with 'export' and doesn't worked (my mistake)

but, the trick is to put all in the same line, and so I  achieved with this:

```
PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD=abc123 PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL=email@email.com /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh --yes
```

**Refer**

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BOCxox6sBt_PF1Y7AoEiR1vXhGqr1MP%2Bdya8Y-g7UAD0fUpig%40mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs across this thread and can't get the other answers to work (because the script requires sudo), try the '-E' flag to preserve environment variables for sudo.

```bash
export PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL="testuser@test.com"
export PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD="testpass"
sudo -E /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh --yes
```